# Reset and load data in view model using MVVM Light ViewModelLocator

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light

**UPDATE Below**

New to the WPF party, apologies if this has been asked before.

I want to do a popup window to create an entity and another (or the same if recommended) to edit / update but can't easily get an empty ViewModel or load data for the edit.

**ViewModelLocator**

```
public ViewModelLocator()
{
    ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => SimpleIoc.Default);
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<MainViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<CreateViewModel>();
    SimpleIoc.Default.Register<EditViewModel>();
}

public MainViewModel Main
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<MainViewModel>();
    }
}

public CreateViewModel Create
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<CreateViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}

public EditViewModel Edit
{
    get
    {
        return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<EditViewModel>(Guid.NewGuid().ToString());
    }
}
```

**Main.xaml** (using same method for create and edit)

```
<Window
//Hide namespaces, etc.
DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">
```

In MainViewModel I have a command that opens up a new window for create

```
Create create = new Create();
create.ShowDialog();
```

Which if I type data in a textbox and close using the method below, the data is stil there when I reopen, I had used the `Guid.NewGuid()` in the viewmodellocator to stop it being a singleton, however, no joy.

**CreateViewModel**
    public CreateViewModel()
    {
        CloseWindowCommand = new RelayCommand(this.CloseWindow);
    }

```
private void CloseWindow(DXRibbonWindow window)
{
    if (window != null)
    {
        window.Close();
    }
}
```

I imagine if I can get the create window cleared out, I can use the following code to load data in the edit window.

```
var editVM = (new ViewModelLocator()).Edit;
editVM.LoadData(id);
```

or use a messenger.

**TLDR**
How do I use the MVVMLight ViewModelLocator to load a View with a fresh ViewModel when the View window is opened.

**UPDATE**
I didn't have the `Guid.NewGuid().ToString())` in my correct viewmodel property so now I can open up a window with a fresh viewmodel, however, I would still like clarification on this if possible.

Comment: Create create = new Create();create.DataContext=new CreateViewModel();
create.ShowDialog();

Comment: Dhaval, I've moved away from this method to datacontext in the viewmodel so don't want this approach.